# Clarification for the change of order of integral and infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

In going through the solution of part (b) in [here](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/courses/185f09/math185f09-hw7sol.pdf), I am curious about the justification for the interchange of the integral and the infinite sum as the uniform convergence is not that clear. Here $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ and $D(0; 1)$ is the open unit disk.

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(0;1)} \frac{1}{z} e^{\beta (z+1/z)}~dz = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\beta^n}{n !} \left[ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(0;1)} \frac{e^{\beta z}}{z^{n+1}}~dz  \right] .$$

Comment: That is a straight use of Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem.